# how to make a for statement to select rows in excel sheet by name i

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, for-loop

I want to use pandas to read an excel sheet and print the rows corresponding to a name.  So far my code works to call a single name:

```
import pandas as pd 

Data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx", sheet_name='Pipeline', header=None)

Advm = Data.loc[(Data[0]=='ADVM')]
print(Advm)
```

which returns the data from my workbook only for the specified name:

```
0                  1  ...         3               4
1  ADVM     ADVM-022 OPTIC  ...   Phase I  Catalyst Soon?
2  ADVM  ADVM-022 INFINITY  ...  Phase II  Catalyst Soon?
```

It doesn't seem to work when I add the for statement to go through all the names I have:

```
import pandas as pd 

Data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx", sheet_name='Pipeline', header=None)
stocks = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx",sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)

for i in stocks:
        t = Data.loc[(Data[0]==i)]
        print(t)
```

which returns:

```
[2 rows x 5 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Index: []
```

I was wondering what I could do to fix this.  The Data sheet has multiple rows with the same name.  The stocks sheet has only one of each name.  I don't want to change the data in either, just to loop the retrieval of each name's data.  Thanks!

I was using this site for reference: https://datatofish.com/select-rows-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: are you sure the column names in stocks are equal the values in Data[0]?

Answer (score 0):

May have figured it out already.

```
import pandas as pd 

Ticklist = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx",sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)
stocks = Ticklist.values.ravel()

Data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Eyes Trial Data Center.xlsx", sheet_name='Pipeline', header=None)

for i in stocks:
    t = Data.loc[(Data[0]==i)]
    print(t)
```

Don't really understand why, but the ravel() function was needed for the i in stocks part to work correctly.